# Not all the labels and text fields on my form do have the same color

Tags: forms, ms-access, colors

Here is the guy with the baptism access program again.

The program is live no for about one month and so far so good and I want to thank all the people who helped me.
There are a few minor problems. One of them is this:
I made a form with a lot of fields in it. although all of these labels and text fields do have the same foreground and background color settings, when I show the form on screen some of the fields have other colors.

I checked and doubled checked all the labels and text fields in the form to be sure that they have the same settings.

I searched the internet if there is an issue about this, but didn't find anything

Comment: This is not a coding issue but design. Does this happen on any computer? Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.